# How to use java @repeatable with cucumber

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have different string for same businesses logic in cucumber.
So I trying to get a way to tag a multiple Gherkins string with one function.

I am trying with below but I m not able understand to formulate it with cucumber

[Using @Repeatable while mainaining support for Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542534/using-repeatable-while-mainaining-support-for-java-7)

Example:

```
Scenario Outline: Looking up the definition of fruits
    the user is on the Wikionary home page for fruits
    When the user looks up the definition of the word <name>
    Then they should see the definition 'An edible fruit produced by the pear tree, similar to an apple but elongated towards the stem.'
    Examples:
    | name |
    | pear | 

Scenario Outline: Looking up the definition of orange
    Given the user is on the Wikionary home page for orange
    When the user looks up the definition of the word <name>
    Then they should see the definition 'An edible fruit produced by the pear tree, similar to an apple but elongated towards the stem.'
    Examples:
    | name |
    | pear |
```

In above statement Given is different but the business function is same.
How I can tag this with repeatable with java.

Or any other way except concatenate string with |

Any work around will be helpful!!!

Comment: Why dont u just change the pattern to -  ^the user is on the Wikionary home page for (orange|fruits)$ - for the step def?

Comment: It is an example grasshopper .. the main string can be absolutely different. .. that's the issue

Comment: While pipe is not working for me if I also try to put whole complete string ... Pipe or OR

Comment: U can try with an non-capturing group -- (?:\\w+)... No need to add arguments for this in the method

Comment: (?\\w+) means any string ... If it will work that it can work for me grasshopper :) ... In case I am also take example data ,is it working like same ?

Comment: I am unable to understand the last part. Can u clarify

Comment: Means I am using sceanrio outline .. so I have example data .. can I use the example data with this (?\\w+)

Comment: it sshould work for scenariooutline

Comment: Means so I need to add in stepdefination like (?\\w+) (.?) Something ... Can you please share an example of Same

Comment: Please add an sample function with genric string with regrex which I can pass to a function ... I have 3 paremeter in my single string ... It would help alot

Answer (score 1):

Have a step definition like this - It should match any similar step and also non-capturing

```
    @Given("^the user is on the Wikionary home page for (?:\\w+)$")
    public void given() {
        System.out.println("givn");
    }
```

---

```
@Given("^should go to given (?:,*) $")

@Given("^should go to given - (.*?) - (?:,*) $")

@Given("^should go to given - (.*?) - (.*?) - (?:,*) $")
```

This will take in different parameters. But this will completely ruin the gherkin step text, make it total gibberish. Would be very uncomfortable using this.

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper .... But if I just use (?:\\w+)$ only as I want my all given should hit that function , moreover if I also want to pass parameters

Comment: Now i got what u want... All Given steps have to call the same stepdefinition method, not just different ending word. I do not think that is possible as Cucumber dos not differentiate between Given, Then and When annotation. They are kind of like marker annotations. Only pattern matching decides what method gets called. Only way to get this done is to use a fixed text in the step text and regex pattern, followed by a ".*" to match the actual step. You can have multiple methods with the same text taking in zero, one, two etc number of parameters. Seems like a hack but will work

Comment: Thanks Grasshopper I will give a try as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the Step Definition Java code only once for above both scenario it will automatically run the same step definition code for the two different scenarios:

```
Scenario Outline: Looking up the definition of fruits
Given the user is on the Wikionary home page for "fruits"

Scenario Outline: Looking up the definition of orange
Given the user is on the Wikionary home page for "orange"
```

For above @Given statement you can write only one step defination method it will automatically execute for both scenario as per the different parameters configuration:

```
@Given("the user is on the Wikionary home page for (.*))
public void given(String fruitName) 
{
        System.out.println(fruitName);
 }
```

Comment: I know this... the question is tagging one stepdefination with different given statements which having completely different statement/string... i guess i need to chNge my example here